# What is the change in time complexity due to substitution of variables?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

This is a question I have after listening to a lecture.

```
def gosperize(curve):
    scaled_curve = scale(sqrt(2)/2)(curve)
    left_curve = rotate(pi/4)(scaled_curve)
    right_curve = translate(0.5,0.5)(rotate(-pi/4)(scaled_curve))

    return connect_rigidly(left_curve, right_curve)

def gosper_curve(level):
    return repeated(gosperize, level)(curve)

def identity(x):
    return x

def repeated(f, n):
    if (n == 0):
       return identity
    return composed(f, repeated(f, n-1))

def rotate(angle):
    def transform(curve):
        def rotated_curve(t):
            pt = curve(t)
            x, y = x_of(pt), y_of(pt)
            cos_a, sin_a = cos(angle), sin(angle)

            return make_point(cos_a*x - sin_a*y, sin_a*x + cos_a*y)
        return rotated_curve
    return transform

def joe_rotate(angle):
    def transform(curve):
        def rotated_curve(t):
            x, y = x_of(curve(t)), y_of(curve(t))
            cos_a, sin_a = cos(angle), sin(angle)

            return make_point(cos_a*x - sin_a*y, sin_a*x + cos_a*y)
        return rotated_curve
    return transform
```

I think this is all the code that is needed to contextualise my question properly. The lecture was on an abstraction on curves. It was mentioned that for the function `gosper_curve`,if `joe_rotate` is used instead of `rotate`, `gosper_curve` will turn into a process whose time is linear in the level into one which is exponential in the level. I do not understand how assigning `pt=curve(t)` could change the time complexity of the function. I would appreciate any help on my order of growth fundamentals.

Comment: Indeed, the difference between `joe_rotate` and `rotate` seem bounded by a constant to me. Are you sure that this is the only difference? Are there lecture notes or something else the lecture was based on that explicitly defines these functions such that we can see their exact difference (it seem likely either the lecturer has made a mistake or you made a mistake in transcribing the material, it would be useful to find out what is the case!)

Comment: @Discretelizard yea I'm pretty sure it's the only difference since I copied it exactly from the slides. It seems weird to me, thats why I'm asking for help here.

Comment: Could you provide a link to those slides? Some more context could make this issue a lot clearer.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Please get rid of the source code and replace it with ideas, pseudo code and arguments of correctness. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/64/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/390/) for related meta discussions.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: @Discretelizard I do not have the link to the slides as they are not published. I only have a python file with those functions that is an abstract modelling of curves, and I have posted some of these functions which I think are helpful to this issue. If u want I could post more of it, basically if ur wondering what is curve(t), it's just assigning a t-value to curve function so that u get a "point" object with (x,y) coordinates. All the functions here are all on curves transformation so I think points wouldnt be a major concern

Comment: @Raphael Hi, sry I wasnt v clear about the policy in cs stackexchange vs stack overflow before asking a question(seems in here u need to ask generic questions without referring to actual code). Is it possible to move this post to stack overflow instead? I'm actually not aware how to shift it there too.

Comment: @Discretelizard I thought of something. Is it true that when u write `pt=curve(t)`, assuming `curve(t)` returns a value and is stored in `pt`, when `pt` is called in `x, y = x_of(pt), y_of(pt)` , there is technically only 1 function call on `curve(t)`(the first time u assigned the value to `pt`) since calling `pt`again twice doesnt call `curve(t)` again, but only transfers the stored value into the `x_of `and `y_of`

Comment: This _is_ the better place for runtime analysis questions, but we don't like source code. Rewriting the algorithm to pseudo code (i.e. code that doesn't need specific PL knowledge to understand it) is your best bet for good answers. If you insist, we can migrate to [SO], too.

Comment: @Raphael I think I will stick here for now.

Comment: Please credit the source of all copied material, including copied code.  You have copied code from somewhere else, so even if you can't link to it, it should be possible to provide some kind of credit/identification of the source -- see https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.